# If $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=0\; \text{ for all } n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\},$ Then which one is right.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> If $f$ is a differentiable function satisfying $$f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=0\; \text{ for all } n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\},$$ Then which one is right.

$\bf{Options::}$ $(a)\;\; f(0)=f'(0)=0\;\;\;\;\;\; (b)\;\; \left|f(x)\right|\leq 1, x\in (0,1)\;\;\;\;\;\; (c)\;\; f(x)=0,x\in (0,1)$

$(d)\;\;\;\; f(0) =0$ but $f'(0)$ not necessary zero.

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ If function $f$ is differentiable, Then it must be continuous.

So $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = f(0) =0$$

Now I did not understand How $f'(0) = 0$

Help me

Thanks

Comment: For a counter-example to (b) and (c) let$ f(0)=0,$ and for $x \ne 0$ let $f(x)=2 x^2\sin (1/2\pi x).$

Answer (score 4):

Well for one thing if $f$ is differentiable at $0$ then,

$$f'(0) = \lim_{x - 0} \dfrac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} = \lim_n \dfrac{f(\frac 1 n) - f(0)}{ \frac 1 n - 0} = 0$$

Answer (score 3):

If $f'(0)$ exists, then it must be equal to

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(1/n) - f(0)}{1/n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{0-0}{1/n} = 0.$$

Put another way, if $\lim_{h \to 0} g(h)$ exists then it must be equal to $\lim_{k \to \infty} g(h_k)$ whenever $h_k \to 0$.